# How to make size based throttler using akka fsm?

Tags: scala, throttling, akka-fsm

I have a use case that i have to process the request using akka fsm as soon as number of request reaches to specified value.

```
sealed trait State
case object Idle extends State
case object Active extends State

sealed trait Data
case object Uninitialized extends Data
case object QuickStart extends Data
case class A(a: Int) extends Data

class RequestHandlers extends FSM[State, Data] {
  val queue = mutable.Queue[A]()
  startWith(Idle, Uninitialized)

  when(Idle) {
    case Event(_, Uninitialized) =>
      println("At Idle")
      //      self ! QuickStart
      goto(Active) using QuickStart
  }

  when(Active) {
    case Event(_, request: A) =>
      println("At Active")
      queue.take(2).map{x => println("request---  " + x.a  + "processing")
      queue.dequeue()
```

}

```
      Thread.sleep(2000L)
      goto(Active) using Uninitialized
  }


  whenUnhandled {
    case Event(update: A, QuickStart) =>
      queue += update
      if(queue.size >= 2) {
        println(s"At unhandled + ${update}" + "--" + queue)
        goto(Active) using update
      }
      else {
        println("size has not reached")
        goto(Active) using Uninitialized
      }
    case Event(update: A, Uninitialized) =>
      queue += update
      println(s"At unhandled - Uninitialised + $update")
      goto(Active) using QuickStart
  }

  initialize()

}

object demo extends App  {

  val actorSystem = ActorSystem("system")
  val actor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props(classOf[RequestHandlers]))

  val list = (1 to 10).toList
  list.foreach { abc =>

    actor ! Uninitialized
    actor ! A(abc)
    println("Sent")
  }

}
```

I tried to using mutable queue where i am adding my request. After size of queue reaches to certain value i.e 2 process those requests simultaneously.
After processing, i am dequeuing it. If i send 10 request, it will process 8 request but for last 2 it will never go to active state.
I am not getting where i am making mistake while transition.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the minimal example of what you are doing looks like this:

```
// The only type of incoming message
case class Msg(a: Int)

// States
sealed trait State
case object Waiting extends State
case object Active extends State

// StateData is shared between states
case class StateData(queue: immutable.Queue[Msg])
object StateData {
  val empty = StateData(immutable.Queue.empty)

  def single(msg: Msg) = StateData(immutable.Queue(msg))
}


class RequestHandlers extends FSM[State, StateData] {
  val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

  def curTime = {
    val time = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000f
    f"[$time%3.2f]"
  }

  startWith(Waiting, StateData.empty)

  onTransition {
    case Waiting -> Active =>
      //use nextStateData rather than stateData !
      nextStateData match {
        case StateData(queue) =>
          queue.foreach(x => println(s"$curTime processing ${x.a} "))
          Thread.sleep(2000L)
      }
  }

  when(Active) {
    case Event(msg: Msg, _) =>
      println(s"$curTime at Active $msg")
      // we've just processed old data
      // drop the old queue and create a new one with the new message
      goto(Waiting) using StateData.single(msg)
  }
  when(Waiting) {
    case Event(msg: Msg, StateData(oldQueue)) =>
      // add an event to the queue and check if it is time to process
      val newQueue = oldQueue :+ msg
      println(s"$curTime at Idle $msg, newQueue = $newQueue")
      if (newQueue.size == 2) {
        goto(Active) using StateData(newQueue)
      }
      else {
        stay using StateData(newQueue)
      }
  }

  initialize()
}
```

and the test program is

```
object demo extends App  {

    val actorSystem = ActorSystem("system")
    val actor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props(classOf[RequestHandlers]))

    (1 to 10).toList.foreach { i =>
      println(s"Send $i")
      actor ! Msg(i)
    }

}
```

The logic of `RequestHandlers` is that it accumulates incomming requests in a queue stored inside a `StateData` object (which has only one type that is shared between both states). There are two states `Waiting` and `Active`. The processing actually happens on the transition `Waiting` -> `Active`. Probably the most tricky point is to not forget that when FSM is in the `Active` state, new messages will arrive and should be processed by adding to a queue (or rather starting a new queue with the data from that message).

P.S. Well, this example is probably not that minimal. In fact you could have just one state and do the processing inside `if (newQueue.size == 2)` but that would be a quite strange FSM.

Comment: Thanks, it is working fine. I am trying to understand it. Could you also tell me the mistake which i am doing in my code.

Comment: @MaheshChandKandpal, there are too many mistakes to name just one. The most important probably is that you don't understand the role of the `D` generic parameter is `FSM[S,D]`. `D` is a piece of data associated with a state and this is why I called it `StateData` in my example. This is a trick to avoid you having a lot of similar `State` objects that are different only by data. Making your `A` extend `Data` makes no sense. Also the same `D` is what comes as the second part of the `Event` and your usage of it seems wrong in almost all of the places.

Comment: Yes, i don't know how to work with it. I am just trying to do by using some examples on internet. Thanks a ton.